# java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for app requiring camera permissions

Tags: java, android

This is for a simple Android flashlight app. Checked the Dev Console and see two crashes / ANRS. Not sure how to debug this because there are so many Android devices and it's hard to test them physically [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArTz9.png)

One of them is for a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flash/com.example.flash.FlashLightActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at com.example.flash.FlashLightActivity.onCreate(FlashLightActivity.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
... 11 more
```

The other is for a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
at com.example.flash.FlashLightActivity.onCreate(FlashLightActivity.java:89)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Update:
Looks like line 89 is causing it because of API level differences:

```
 mCameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Post FlashLightActivity. [mcve]

Comment: The second one should be easy to debug, as it shows you exactly in the code where you are crashing. Since we cannot see line 89 of `FlashlightActivity`, we cannot help you with that.